# Spectral radius for Jacobi and Gauss Seidel iterative methods

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let 
$
L=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & \ldots & & &  &0 \\
a & 0 & \ldots &  &  &0 \\
0 & a & 0 & \ldots &  &0\\
0 & 0& a & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$

that is $L$ has its sub-diagonal equal to $a$, the other elements are zero.

Show that

$$
\rho(L+L^T)^2 = \rho((\text{Id}+L)^{-1} L^T) 
$$

where $\rho(M)$ is the spectral radius of the matrix $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only remember the following proof. So there might be an easier way.

**Definiton 1:**
 Let $A∈ℝ^{n×n}$ be a matrix with $$A=L+D+R,$$
with $D$ invertible.
If the eigenvalues of the matrix $$J(α)=-D^{-1}\{αL+α^{-1}R\}, α∈ℂ\setminus\{0\}$$
are independent of $α$, then we call $A$ *consistently ordered*.

---

**Theorem 1**: Tri-diagonal matrices of the following form are consistently ordered.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
d_1 & a_{12} & \\
a_{21}& d_2 & \ddots \\
& \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-1,n} \\
& & a_{n-1,n} & d_n
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $d_i\neq0$.
Why? 
Let $T=\text{diag}(1, α, …, α^{n-1})$, then we can do a similarity transformation: 
$$-J(α) = αD^{-1}L+α^{-1}D^{-1}R = T(D^{-1}L+D^{-1}R)T^{-1}$$
And we know that eigenvalues are preserved under similarity transformation.

---

In your case it is $A=L+I+L^\top$, which is a tri-diagonal matrix. Hence your matrix is consistently ordered. And the two matrices where you want to know the spectral radii are simply the Jacobi-matrix $J=D^{-1}(L+R)$ and the Gauß-Seidel-matrix $H=-(D+L)^{-1}L^\top$ of that $A$.

---

**Theorem 2**: 
Let $A∈ℝ^{n×n}$ be a consistently ordered matrix. Then the eigenvalues $μ∈σ(J)$ and $λ∈σ(H_ω)$ fulfil: 
$$\sqrt{λ}ωμ = λ+ω-1.$$

Probably $ω∈(0,2)$, so that the SOR-method converges. I don't remember the proof. You should be able to find it somewhere in these [lecture notes](http://numerik.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/~lehre/notes/numla/NumLinAlg.pdf). (I was an exercise group leader to that lecture, that is why I remember this answer.)

---

The Gauß-Seidel-matrix is the special case of the SOR-matrix $H_ω$ with $ω=1$. Hence: 
$$ρ(H_1)=ρ(J)^2$$

Comment: What do you mean by "the eigenvalues fulfil"? There is more than one eigenvalue for both matrices.

Comment: Also, in your definition (and in Theorem 1) you should add that $D$ is supposed to be invertible and $\alpha\neq 0$.

Comment: Thx for your comments. I corrected what you mentioned in the second comment.  About the first one: Well both matrices have eigenvalues and for each eigenvalue $λ_i$ of $J$ there is an eigenvalue $µ_i$ of $H_ω$ which is related by that equation.

Comment: Ok. I think you should correct this, too, because it is very confusing without that explanation. And is it clear that $H_\omega$ has only non-negative real eigenvalues?

Comment: @amsmath - No, in general they are complex.

Comment: So, what's $\sqrt\lambda$ then? And you still should correct your statement.

Comment: I don't see a problem with calculating square roots of complex numbers. And no, I will not correct my statement, as there is nothing to correct.

Comment: Yes, there is - it is simply not correct stated this way, but nevermind... I am sure you know that there are always two chooices for the square root. So, which one will you choose? Or do you choose both? The problem with your statement is that is has to be interpreted - and this can be done in various ways. This is not proper math in my opinion.